# Unix cut except last two tokens

Tags: linux, bash, unix, token, cut

I'm trying to parse file names in specific directory. Filenames are of format:

```
token1_token2_token3_token(N-1)_token(N).sh
```

I need to cut the tokens using delimiter `'_'`, and need to take string except the last two tokens. In above examlpe output should be `token1_token2_token3`.

The number of tokens is not fixed. I've tried to do it with `-f#-` option of `cut` command, but did not find any solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

With cut:

```
$ echo t1_t2_t3_tn1_tn2.sh | rev | cut -d_ -f3- | rev
t1_t2_t3
```

rev reverses each line.
The `3-` in `-f3-` means from the 3rd field to the end of the line (which is the beginning of the line through the third-to-last field in the unreversed text).

Comment: This works like a charm :D And yes as asked in the question it uses cut command. I will choose this answer.

Comment: Answered my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644000/how-to-get-second-last-field-from-a-cut-command/17644034?noredirect=1#17644034 too. Thanks

Comment: I fell in love with this answer. I keep forgetting about the existance of rev.

Comment: Wonderful! Worked with bash for 20 years, never knew about rev.

Comment: what if you don't know how many tokens there will be and you want all but the last one?

Comment: @Michael then do `| rev | cut -d_ -f2- | rev`.  2- is second field through last field in the reversed text, which is first field through next-to-last field in the original text

Answer (score 8):

It can not be done with `cut`, However, you can use `sed`

```
sed -r 's/(_[^_]+){2}$//g'
```

Answer (score 7):

You may use POSIX defined parameter substitution:

```
$ name="t1_t2_t3_tn1_tn2.sh"
$ name=${name%_*_*}
$ echo $name
t1_t2_t3
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a different way to write ysth's answer :

```
echo "t1_t2_t3_tn1_tn2.sh" |rev| cut -d"_" -f1,2 --complement | rev
```