# How do I split string on last "-" in bash?

Tags: bash, split

Given the string `"foo-bar-1.4.5"` or `"for-bar-baz-1.8.3"` how can I break these strings into 2 parts: first part everything before the last "-" (`"foo-bar"`, `"foo-bar-baz"`) and the last part (`"1.4.5"` and `"1.8.3"`) respectively?

I can imagine a few strategies, like splitting on "-" then adding everything but the last part back together. Or maybe a regex with substitution. Bash is the biggest thing in my way though. I'm not sure what the syntax would look like and I've tried a few things with `sed` and `awk` but my lack of comfort with bash arrays is hanging me up. I figure one of you bash experts can bang this out in short order and teach me via an example pretty fast.

**EDIT**: I won't know the number of "-" before the command is run. The method should handle `n >= 1` of "-".

Comment: What is your input source? Do you have a file full of these, or a stream? You're not against sed & awk? What about Perl?

Comment: (in other words, you're comfortable with more than raw bash for this?)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowsk I only have packages installed with fresh debian:jessie. So perl is out. But `sed` and `awk` are ok.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get second last field from a cut command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644000/how-to-get-second-last-field-from-a-cut-command)

Comment: [Bash can do lots of stuff all by itself.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100)

Comment: (in short `echo "foo-bar-bax-1.8.3" | awk -F'-' '{print $(NF-1)}'` or something)

Comment: @njzk2 I disagree with the duplication suggestions. Even if the tools used to solve the problem are the same, the goal is different. Your method looks interesting though! I didn't know about NF.

Comment: You could use `cut` too!

Comment: @thedeeno: the linked question is about getting the `second last field`. getting the last field is rather close, I would say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) for this:

`${var#pattern}` removes the shortest matching pattern from the beginning of var. Using ## removes the longest matching pattern. % and %% work similarly, but remove from the end of var.

```
#!/bin/bash
first="foo-bar-1.4.5"
second="foo-bar-baz-1.8.3"

echo ${first%-*}
echo ${first##*-}

echo ${second%-*}
echo ${second##*-}
```

Output:

```
foo-bar
1.4.5
foo-bar-baz
1.8.3
```

Comment: I won't know how many "-" before the command is run. This looks like the count must be hard coded right?

Comment: No, I will clarify in the answer.

Comment: @Mat maybe I don't understand yet, but see `a%` and `%b`

Comment: @thedeeno: the test variables are `stringa` and `stringb`, the a and b are not part of the magic. The magic starts at `%` and `##` respectively. The link I posted as a comment to your question has much more details (and variations).

Comment: @Mat Thanks for the clarity. My mind parsed the variable name + patterns wrong

Comment: Love this method. So compact!

Answer (score 2):

To use a regular expression in `bash`:

```
s="foo-bar-1.4.5"
[[ $s =~ (.*)-(.*) ]]
name=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
version=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
```

`bash` only uses greedy matching, so the first `.*` will match as much as possible, leaving only the last `-` to match the literal `-` in the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash` built-in features is the right way to go. However, for reference, here is an option using `awk`:

```
$ cat file
foo-bar-1.4.5
for-bar-baz-1.8.3
```

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="-"}{last = $NF; NF--; printf "First = %s\nLast = %s\n", $0, last}' file
First = foo-bar
Last = 1.4.5
First = for-bar-baz
Last = 1.8.3
```