# How do I obtain a specific row with the cut command?

Tags: cut

## Background

I have a file, named `yeet.d`, that looks like this

```
JET_FUEL = /steel/beams
ABC_DEF = /michael/jackson
....50 rows later....
SHIA_LEBEOUF = /just/do/it
....73 rows later....
GIVE_FOOD = /very/hungry
NEVER_GONNA = /give/you/up
```

I am familiar with the [`f and d`](https://alvinalexander.com/linux-unix/linux-cut-command-cut-fields-columns-examples) options of the [`cut`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) command.  The `f` option allows you to specify which column(s) to extract from, while the `d` option allows you to specify what the delimiters.

## Problem

I want this output returned using the `cut` command.

```
/just/do/it
```

From what I know, this is part of the command I want to enter:

```
cut -f1 -d= yeet.d
```

Given that I want the values to the right of the equals sign, with the equals sign as the delimiter. However this would return:

```
/steel/beams
/michael/jackson
....50 rows later....
/just/do/it
....73 rows later....
/very/hungry
/give/you/up
```

Which is more than what I want.

## Question

How do I use the `cut` command to return **only** `/just/do/it` and nothing else from the situation above? This is different from [How to get second last field from a cut command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644000/how-to-get-second-last-field-from-a-cut-command) because I want to select a row within a large file, not just near from the end or the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it would be easier to express with `awk`...

```sh
# awk -v _s="${_string}" '$3 == _s {print $3}' "${_path}"

## Above could be more _scriptable_ form of bellow example

awk -v _search="/just/do/it" '$3 == _search {print $3}' <<'EOF'
JET_FULE = /steal/beams
SHIA_LEBEOUF = /just/do/it
NEVER_GONNA = /give/you/up
EOF

## Either way, output should be similar to
##  /just/do/it
```

- *`-v _something="Some Thing"`* bit allows for passing Bash variables to `awk`
- *`$3 == _search`* bit tells `awk` to match only when column `3` is equal to the `search` string

  - To search for a sub-string within a line one can use *`$0 ~ _search`*
- *`{print $3}`* bit tells `awk` to `print` column `3` for any matches
- And the *`<<'EOF'`* bit tells Bash to not expand anything within the opening and closing *`EOF`* *tags*

... however, the above will still output duplicate matches, eg. if `yeet.d` somehow contained...

```
JET_FULE = /steal/beams
SHIA_LEBEOUF = /just/do/it
NEVER_GONNA = /give/you/up
AGAIN = /just/do/it
```

... there'd be two `/just/do/it` lines outputed by `awk`.

Quickest way around that would be to pipe `|` to `head -1`, but the *better* way would be to tell `awk` to `exit` after it's been told to `print`...

```sh
_string='/just/do/it'
_path='yeet.d'

awk -v _s="${_string}" '$3 == _s {print $3; exit}' "${_path}"
```

... though that now assumes that only the first match is wanted, obtaining the *`n`th* is possible though currently outside the scope of the question as of last time read.

---

### Updates

To *trip* `awk` on the first column while printing the third column and exiting after the first match may look like...

```sh
_string='SHIA_LEBEOUF'
_path='yeet.d'

awk -v _s="${_string}" '$1 == _s {print $3; exit}' "${_path}"
```

... and generalize even further...

```sh
_string='^SHIA_LEBEOUF '
_path='yeet.d'

awk -v _s="${_string}" '$0 ~ _s {print $3; exit}' "${_path}"
```

... because `awk` *totally gets* regular expressions, *mostly*.

Comment: So this is absolutely a great way to answer the question hence +1.  However, in my context, I really only know the left side (SHIA_LEBEOUF) and want to obtain the right side.  The answer by @flappix contains a way that does this more generically.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @isakbob, I've updated my answer to hopefully show ya that `awk` is something worth looking into. There's an entire [scripting](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Executable-Scripts.html) language available, so as projects grow it's possible to make reusable bits... and that's not even getting into how much faster things can run by adopting `awk` into the workflow... Let us know with an `awk` question if ya get stuck on some edge-case, perhaps tag me if ya wish, as it can sometimes be difficult to find up-to date documentation on such things.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to identify the desired line.

You could identify it by the line number. In this case you can use sed

```
cut -f2 -d= yeet.d | sed '53q;d'
```

This extracts the 53th line.

Or you could identify it by a keyword. In this case use grep

```
cut -f2 -d= yeet.d | grep just
```

This extracts all lines containing the word *just*.